# How to get peak change of array list in O(1)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have an array of `integer`

```
e.g. int a[10]=[3,4,6,8,10,9,6,5,4,2],
```

i mean the contents inside the array will be in increasing order then decreasing,

I want to find out the peak point of change (last greater value and index) 
e.g. in above case is `10`, within order of `1`,

please note we can do in `O(n)` by comparing and making the note of change but I need help to solve this in less than `O(n)` complexity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only achieve this in O(1) if the array is ordered in the first place, then it would be either the first or the last element. However Ordering cannot be achieved in O(1) or O(n) in a general case.

Comment: Do you perhaps know that the array is always "symmetrical"? If so, the answer could be as simple as `max(a[a.length/2], a[a.length/2 + 1])`.

Comment: no this will not work because its not mandatory your max value will be always in mid it could be second last as well e.g.[1,2,3,5,6,7,4,3]

Answer (score 2):

We can do this using `Binary search` suppose we are at our current `mid` value, the by looking at the index `mid - 1` and at the index `mid + 1`, we can check whether the sequence is decreasing or increasing, and accordingly we can make a decision about which half we want to search the answer in.

We know we have found the answer when :

`arr[mid - 1] < arr[mid] && arr[mid + 1] < arr[mid]`

Pseudo code :

```
int start = 0, end = n;
while(start <= end){
    int mid = (start + end)/2;
    if(mid - 1 >= 0 && mid + 1 <= n && arr[mid-1] >= arr[mid] && arr[mid] >= arr[mid+1]){
        //decreasing part
        end = mid-1;
    }else if(mid - 1 >= 0 && mid + 1 <= n && arr[mid-1] <= arr[mid] && arr[mid] <= arr[mid+1]){
        //increasing part
        start = mid+1;
    }else{
        //answer found, take care of corner cases
        cout << arr[mid] << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

The complexity of this solution is O(log2(n)), I don't think a better solution is possible, since you need to search peak, and that can only be done by making comparisions so a O(1) solution might not be possible.

Demo in c++ : http://ideone.com/UXwyaT

Comment: its not working ,not coming out from while loop,please can you suggest which is working in your environment,else no use to spend time and correcting others code. thanks

Comment: You have to break out of the while loop when you find the answer, i have added a c++ solution that works.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @u_seem_surprised answer, this definetly cannot be done better than `Omega(logn)`.

**Proof:**

The index of the peak has `n` different possibilities for an array of size `n`.

It means, for each index `i`, we can find an array that the result should be this index, `i`.

Using comparisons based model, we need `Omega(log_2(n))` to determine which of these `n` values is the correct one.

So we can conclude, lower bound for this problem is `Omega(log(n))`.